# How do I create a read-only entity?

Tags: jpa, orm, entity

I have a web application using J2EE + Spring and a MySQL database. I need one entity which will be read-only. I have one main table with products, and they are only to read. There should be no insertion of new records and no updates currently.

The entity class should only read data and pass the entities forward (other entities are tables like order, shipments etc.).

Is there any solution for this? Does anyone have the same issue? Thanks for the help.

Comment: and the problem is ? the developer is the only person who can update it. what behaviour are you expecting? and under what situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't change an object, it will never be updated.

If you are using EclipseLink you can use the @ReadOnly annotation to mark something as read-only.